# Clock gating on Tiva Launchpad

Tags: embedded, arm, gpio

I am working on a Tiva launchpad board and want to use the GPIO. I have successfully enabled the clock on PORTF using this line of code:

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = 0x20U;
```

So I tried changing the above line to the one shown below:

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= (5 << 1U);
```

This did not work. Will someone explain the difference between the two.

Comment: This is all standard C syntax, which is well documented all over the internet. What exactly is confusing to you?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the first line works. If  replace it with the second it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Lets convert all of your integer values to binary for easier comparison.

```
    0x20 -> 0b00100000
    5    -> 0b00000101
(5 << 1) -> 0b00001010
```

I think you can already see the problem.

If, however, you did `(1 << 5)` instead, you'd have:

```
    0x20 -> 0b00100000
    1    -> 0b00000001
(1 << 5) -> 0b00100000
```

So, to sum it up, you need to shift `1` left by `5` bits, not shift `5` left by `1` bit.